# Javascript prototype functions always load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a little web site and i need to use javascript. I am having a problem with the functions with prototypes. I was testing some things and i realized that whenever i load my page, the prototype of my functions always run executes. i have this code :

```
    function Clinica ()
{
 var id = 0;
 var doentes = [];


}

Clinica.prototype.criarDoente = new function ()
{
        alert("HELLO");
}
```

the alert is just for test. now i have this HTML :

```
<form id ="criarDoenteForm" onsubmit = javascript: "criarDoente();" >

<label> Número: </label>
<label id ="numero"> </label>
</br>

<label> Nome: </label>
<input type="text" size="20" />
</br>

<label> Sexo: </label>
<input id="masculino" name="sexo" type="radio" value="m" />
<label for="masculino" class="valores">Masculino </label>


<input id="feminino" name="sexo" type="radio" value="m" />
<label for="feminino" class="valores"> Feminino </label>
</br>

<label> Data de Nascimento: </label>
<input type="text" size="10" />
</br>

<input  type="submit" value="Criar" />
<input  type="submit" value="Cancelar" />


</form>
```

so, when i click the submit button it runs the function and it does. BUT, it always loads whenever i refresh the page or open it. Why is this ?

Comment: don't use `new` with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel A. White points out, the `new` is the problem.

When you place `new` before a function, that will execute the function, using it as a constructor for a new object. This will happen even if there aren't any parentheses to invoke the function.

What you are doing here:

```
Clinica.prototype.criarDoente = new function ()
{
        alert("HELLO");
}
```

has essentially the same effect as:

```
var f = function ()
{
        alert("HELLO");
};
Clinica.prototype.criarDoente = new f; // <-- this will execute the function
                                       //     even without parentheses
```

So just remove the `new`:

```
Clinica.prototype.criarDoente = function ()
{
        alert("HELLO");
};
```

Comment: oh , what a rookie mistake. I was asking myself why can i use Clinica Methods without having a Clinica object. I know there are no classes in javascript but i've been told this is the way you can "simulate" them.